# How can i make a Row display like this without making a new class?

Tags: flutter

Im trying to make an new app, and i want to display a row [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulRUH.jpg)

i dont understand the concept behind it, like how can he divide the box into two type of colors, and how can the shape of the box looks like that. anyone that can teach me i will appriciated it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a simple UI layout to create if you are just starting out with Flutter.

Simply put, you have to have a Row containing copies of a widget you create yourself as a stateless widget. The widget tree would look something like this.

```
Row
  CustomWidget
  CustomWidget
  ...
```

The CustomWidget is the complex part, this is a simplified example of how the Widget tree of this widget could look. Create a stateless widget and try to create it yourself.

```
Card
  Column
    Container
      Row
        Icon
        Text
    Container
      Align
        Text
```

Note you will have to set the color property of the Card and Container widgets, and add some padding certain places in the widget tree. Plus, the last container will need a width property as well.

If you need more help - show what you have attempted with code (edit your question)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but i didnt expect someone would answer my question with 3 downvote already, so i code it with my own and it somehow work.

Comment: Sorry but maybe i would try your suggestion later.